# Linear Independence and Orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, combinations, orthogonality, independence

Suppose $w$ is a nonzero vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$. And I suppose that vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent and both orthogonal to $w$.

How do I prove that vector $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is orthogonal to $w$ if and only if $v$ is a linear combination of $v_1$ and $v_2$?

Answer (score 1):

If $v_1,v_2$ are linearly independent and $w$ is orthogonal to both, the triple spans $\mathbb{R}^3$ (orthogonality is a special kind of linear independence).

Furthermore, $v_1$ and $v_2$ live in the orthogonal complement of $w$, a 2 dimensional vector space. Since $v_1$ and $v_2$ are L.I, they span the orthogonal complement and form a basis.

Then if we have $v$ in the orthogonal complement to $w$, we can write $v=c_1v_1+c_2v_2$.

Similarly, for the backward direction, if we have
$$
v=c_1v_1+c_2v_2\implies \langle w,v\rangle=c_1\langle v_1,w\rangle+c_2\langle v_2,w\rangle=0
$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "special kind of linear independence." also, what is meant by live in orthogonal complement? all vectors that form a basis live in such a compliment?

Comment: Meaning all orthogonal vectors are linearly independent vectors but not vice versa. The orthogonal complement is the set of all vectors orthogonal to a given vector.

Comment: I think i just got it. I think i was just being dumb..... haha. thanks.

Comment: @qbert Does linear independence mainly checks that vectors are not colinear?